# Need JavaScript var in anchor

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sure this is really simple, but I need some help.

I'm trying to insert a variable into an anchor in the following snippet

```
var tablerows = ''
  $.each( data, function(index,row){
    id = row.shift()
    tablerows += '<tr><td><a href="getuserimage.php?id=" target="_blank">' + row.shift() + '</a></td>'
    tablerows += '<td>' + row.join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>'
  })
  $("#users-table > tbody").html(tablerows)
```

I'm just not sure how to get the id in there

Comment: By "php var" do you mean "The JavaScript variable defined on line three of the code (which is a global for some unfathomable reason)"

Comment: sorry I'm a little tired this morning, yes I meant javascript

Comment: You got `row.shift()` in there, why are you having problems getting `id` in there too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't PHP, this is JavaScript (jQuery) code. Either way, in JS, stringing a variable into a string constant is easily done:

```
tablerows += '<tr><td><a href="getuserimage.php?id=' + yourVar + '" target="_blank">';
```

Equally easy for PHP:

```
<?php
    $string = '<tr><td><a href="getuserimage.php?id='.$var.'" target="_blank">';
    //or simply:
    echo '<tr><td><a href="getuserimage.php?id='.$var.'" target="_blank">';
?>
```

And so on